# mingw statically linked libcurl, multi prematurely calling REMOVE when using SSL (openssl)

Tags: c++, openssl, mingw, libcurl, msys2

I've compiled libcurl using "mingw32-make mingw32-ssl-zlib" as instructed in the libcurl docs on msys2 on Windows. It compiled no problem. I've been able to link it into my problem. I'm using the libcurl example (https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/asiohiper.html) to get multi working with boost. It works *no problem* with non-SSL URLs, but when I try an SSL URL it receives a REMOVE message and prematurely ends.

What am I missing getting this to work on Windows?

**Automake code:**

```
bin_PROGRAMS = test

test_CPPFLAGS = -std=c++11 \
              -I${curl_inc} \
              -DCURL_STATICLIB

test_SOURCES = \
           test.cpp

test_LDADD = \
          -lboost_system-mt \
             -L${curl_lib} \
             -lcurl \
             -lssl \
             -lcrypto \
             -lwldap32 \
             -lz \
             -lws2_32

test_LDFLAGS = \
            -L${curl_lib} \
            -static-libgcc \
            -static-libstdc++ \
            -static \
            -all-static \
            -mconsole \
            -mwindows
```

**Program output:**

```
Adding easy 00A847D8 to multi 00B81498 (https://www.google.com)
multi_timer_cb: timeout_ms 0
timer_cb:
multi_timer_cb: timeout_ms 1
REMAINING: 1
timer_cb:
multi_timer_cb: timeout_ms 2
REMAINING: 1
timer_cb:
multi_timer_cb: timeout_ms 4
REMAINING: 1
timer_cb:
multi_timer_cb: timeout_ms 8
REMAINING: 1
timer_cb:
opensocket :
Opened socket 216
sock_cb: socket=216, what=2, sockp=00000000
socket callback: s=216 e=00A847D8 what=OUT
Adding data: OUT
setsock: socket=216, act=2, fdp=00A6BE98
watching for socket to become writable
multi_timer_cb: timeout_ms 200
REMAINING: 1
event_cb: action=2
sock_cb: socket=216, what=4, sockp=00A6BE98
socket callback: s=216 e=00A847D8 what=REMOVE

remsock:
multi_timer_cb: timeout_ms -1
timer_cb:
REMAINING: 1
REMAINING: 1
close_socket : 216
done.
* Rebuilt URL to: https://www.google.com/
*   Trying 216.58.193.132...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to www.google.com (216.58.193.132) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
```

**My modified code (really only modified the URL to https and no verify peer and host:**

```
    /***************************************************************************
 *                                  _   _ ____  _
 *  Project                     ___| | | |  _ \| |
 *                             / __| | | | |_) | |
 *                            | (__| |_| |  _ <| |___
 *                             \___|\___/|_| \_\_____|
 *
 * Copyright (C) 2012 - 2017, Daniel Stenberg, <daniel@haxx.se>, et al.
 *
 * This software is licensed as described in the file COPYING, which
 * you should have received as part of this distribution. The terms
 * are also available at https://curl.haxx.se/docs/copyright.html.
 *
 * You may opt to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute and/or sell
 * copies of the Software, and permit persons to whom the Software is
 * furnished to do so, under the terms of the COPYING file.
 *
 * This software is distributed on an "AS IS" basis, WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY
 * KIND, either express or implied.
 *
 ***************************************************************************/

/* <DESC>
 * demonstrate the use of multi socket interface with boost::asio
 * </DESC>
 */
/*
 * This program is in c++ and uses boost::asio instead of libevent/libev.
 * Requires boost::asio, boost::bind and boost::system
 *
 * This is an adaptation of libcurl's "hiperfifo.c" and "evhiperfifo.c"
 * sample programs. This example implements a subset of the functionality from
 * hiperfifo.c, for full functionality refer hiperfifo.c or evhiperfifo.c
 *
 * Written by Lijo Antony based on hiperfifo.c by Jeff Pohlmeyer
 *
 * When running, the program creates an easy handle for a URL and
 * uses the curl_multi API to fetch it.
 *
 * Note:
 *  For the sake of simplicity, URL is hard coded to "www.google.com"
 *
 * This is purely a demo app, all retrieved data is simply discarded by the write
 * callback.
 */


#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <iostream>

#define MSG_OUT stdout /* Send info to stdout, change to stderr if you want */

/* boost::asio related objects
 * using global variables for simplicity
 */
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
boost::asio::deadline_timer timer(io_service);
std::map<curl_socket_t, boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket *> socket_map;

/* Global information, common to all connections */
typedef struct _GlobalInfo
{
  CURLM *multi;
  int still_running;
} GlobalInfo;

/* Information associated with a specific easy handle */
typedef struct _ConnInfo
{
  CURL *easy;
  char *url;
  GlobalInfo *global;
  char error[CURL_ERROR_SIZE];
} ConnInfo;

static void timer_cb(const boost::system::error_code & error, GlobalInfo *g);

/* Update the event timer after curl_multi library calls */
static int multi_timer_cb(CURLM *multi, long timeout_ms, GlobalInfo *g)
{
  fprintf(MSG_OUT, "\nmulti_timer_cb: timeout_ms %ld", timeout_ms);

  /* cancel running timer */
  timer.cancel();

  if(timeout_ms > 0)
  {
    /* update timer */
    timer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::millisec(timeout_ms));
    timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&timer_cb, _1, g));
  }
  else
  {
    /* call timeout function immediately */
    boost::system::error_code error; /*success*/
    timer_cb(error, g);
  }

  return 0;
}

/* Die if we get a bad CURLMcode somewhere */
static void mcode_or_die(const char *where, CURLMcode code)
{
  if(CURLM_OK != code)
  {
    const char *s;
    switch(code)
    {
    case CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM:
      s = "CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM";
      break;
    case CURLM_BAD_HANDLE:
      s = "CURLM_BAD_HANDLE";
      break;
    case CURLM_BAD_EASY_HANDLE:
      s = "CURLM_BAD_EASY_HANDLE";
      break;
    case CURLM_OUT_OF_MEMORY:
      s = "CURLM_OUT_OF_MEMORY";
      break;
    case CURLM_INTERNAL_ERROR:
      s = "CURLM_INTERNAL_ERROR";
      break;
    case CURLM_UNKNOWN_OPTION:
      s = "CURLM_UNKNOWN_OPTION";
      break;
    case CURLM_LAST:
      s = "CURLM_LAST";
      break;
    default:
      s = "CURLM_unknown";
      break;
    case CURLM_BAD_SOCKET:
      s = "CURLM_BAD_SOCKET";
      fprintf(MSG_OUT, "\nERROR: %s returns %s", where, s);
      /* ignore this error */
      return;
    }

    fprintf(MSG_OUT, "\nERROR: %s returns %s", where, s);

    exit(code);
  }
}

/* Check for completed transfers, and remove their easy handles */
static void check_multi_info(GlobalInfo *g)
{
  char *eff_url;
  CURLMsg *msg;
  int msgs_left;
  ConnInfo *conn;
  CURL *easy;
  CURLcode res;

  fprintf(MSG_OUT, "\nREMAINING: %d", g->still_running);

  while((msg = curl_multi_info_read(g->multi, &msgs_left)))
  {
    if(msg->msg == CURLMSG_DONE)
    {
      easy = msg->easy_handle;
      res = msg->data.result;
      curl_easy_getinfo(easy, CURLINFO_PRIVATE, &conn);
      curl_easy_getinfo(easy, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL, &eff_url);
      fprintf(MSG_OUT, "\nDONE: %s => (%d) %s", eff_url, res, conn->error);
      curl_multi_remove_handle(g->multi, easy);
      free(conn->url);
      curl_easy_cleanup(easy);
      free(conn);
    }
  }
}

/* Called by asio when there is an action on a socket */
static void event_cb(GlobalInfo *g, boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket *tcp_socket,
                     int action, const boost::system::error_code & error, int *fdp)
{
  fprintf(MSG_OUT, "\nevent_cb: action=%d", action);

  /* make sure the event matches what are wanted */
  if(*fdp == action || *fdp == CURL_POLL_INOUT)
  {
    curl_socket_t s = tcp_socket->native_handle();
    CURLMcode rc;
    if(error)
      action = CURL_CSELECT_ERR;
    rc = curl_multi_socket_action(g->multi, s, action, &g->still_running);

    mcode_or_die("event_cb: curl_multi_socket_action", rc);
    check_multi_info(g);

    if(g->still_running <= 0)
    {
      fprintf(MSG_OUT, "\nlast transfer done, kill timeout");
      timer.cancel();
    }

    /* keep on watching.
     * the socket may have been closed and/or fdp may have been changed
     * in curl_multi_socket_action(), so check them both */
    if(!error && socket_map.find(s) != socket_map.end() &&
        (*fdp == action || *fdp == CURL_POLL_INOUT))
    {
      if(action == CURL_POLL_IN)
      {
        tcp_socket->async_read_some(boost::asio::null_buffers(),
                boost::bind(&event_cb, g, tcp_socket, action, _1, fdp));
      }
      if(action == CURL_POLL_OUT)
      {
        tcp_socket->async_write_some(boost::asio::null_buffers(),
                boost::bind(&event_cb, g, tcp_socket, action, _1, fdp));
      }
    }
  }
}

/* Called by asio when our timeout expires */
static void timer_cb(const boost::system::error_code & error, GlobalInfo *g)
{
  if(!error)
  {
    fprintf(MSG_OUT, "\ntimer_cb: ");

    CURLMcode rc;
    rc = curl_multi_socket_action(g->multi, CURL_SOCKET_TIMEOUT, 0, &g->still_running);

    mcode_or_die("timer_cb: curl_multi_socket_action", rc);
    check_multi_info(g);
  }
}

/* Clean up any data */
static void remsock(int *f, GlobalInfo *g)
{
  fprintf(MSG_OUT, "\nremsock: ");

  if(f)
  {
    free(f);
  }
}

static void setsock(int *fdp, curl_socket_t s, CURL*e, int act, int oldact, GlobalInfo*g)
{
  fprintf(MSG_OUT, "\nsetsock: socket=%d, act=%d, fdp=%p", s, act, fdp);

  std::map<curl_socket_t, boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket *>::iterator it = socket_map.find(s);

  if(it == socket_map.end())
  {
    fprintf(MSG_OUT, "\nsocket %d is a c-ares socket, ignoring", s);

    return;
  }

  boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket * tcp_socket = it->second;

  *fdp = act;

  if(act == CURL_POLL_IN)
  {
    fprintf(MSG_OUT, "\nwatching for socket to become readable");
    if(oldact != CURL_POLL_IN && oldact != CURL_POLL_INOUT)
    {
      tcp_socket->async_read_some(boost::asio::null_buffers(),
              boost::bind(&event_cb, g, tcp_socket, CURL_POLL_IN, _1, fdp));
    }
  }
  else if (act == CURL_POLL_OUT)
  {
    fprintf(MSG_OUT, "\nwatching for socket to become writable");
    if(oldact != CURL_POLL_OUT && oldact != CURL_POLL_INOUT)
    {
      tcp_socket->async_write_some(boost::asio::null_buffers(),
              boost::bind(&event_cb, g, tcp_socket, CURL_POLL_OUT, _1, fdp));
    }
  }
  else if(act == CURL_POLL_INOUT)
  {
    fprintf(MSG_OUT, "\nwatching for socket to become readable & writable");
    if(oldact != CURL_POLL_IN && oldact != CURL_POLL_INOUT)
    {
      tcp_socket->async_read_some(boost::asio::null_buffers(),
              boost::bind(&event_cb, g, tcp_socket, CURL_POLL_IN, _1, fdp));
    }
    if(oldact != CURL_POLL_OUT && oldact != CURL_POLL_INOUT)
    {
      tcp_socket->async_write_some(boost::asio::null_buffers(),
              boost::bind(&event_cb, g, tcp_socket, CURL_POLL_OUT, _1, fdp));
    }
  }
}

static void addsock(curl_socket_t s, CURL *easy, int action, GlobalInfo *g)
{
  /* fdp is used to store current action */
  int *fdp = (int *) calloc(sizeof(int), 1);

  setsock(fdp, s, easy, action, 0, g);
  curl_multi_assign(g->multi, s, fdp);
}

/* CURLMOPT_SOCKETFUNCTION */
static int sock_cb(CURL *e, curl_socket_t s, int what, void *cbp, void *sockp)
{
  fprintf(MSG_OUT, "\nsock_cb: socket=%d, what=%d, sockp=%p", s, what, sockp);

  GlobalInfo *g = (GlobalInfo*) cbp;
  int *actionp = (int *) sockp;
  const char *whatstr[] = { "none", "IN", "OUT", "INOUT", "REMOVE"};

  fprintf(MSG_OUT,
          "\nsocket callback: s=%d e=%p what=%s ", s, e, whatstr[what]);

  if(what == CURL_POLL_REMOVE)
  {
    fprintf(MSG_OUT, "\n");
    remsock(actionp, g);
  }
  else
  {
    if(!actionp)
    {
      fprintf(MSG_OUT, "\nAdding data: %s", whatstr[what]);
      addsock(s, e, what, g);
    }
    else
    {
      fprintf(MSG_OUT,
              "\nChanging action from %s to %s",
              whatstr[*actionp], whatstr[what]);
      setsock(actionp, s, e, what, *actionp, g);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}

/* CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION */
static size_t write_cb(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *data)
{

  size_t written = size * nmemb;
  char* pBuffer = (char *) malloc(written + 1);

  strncpy(pBuffer, (const char *)ptr, written);
  pBuffer[written] = '\0';

  fprintf(MSG_OUT, "%s", pBuffer);

  free(pBuffer);

  return written;
}

/* CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION */
static int prog_cb(void *p, double dltotal, double dlnow, double ult,
                   double uln)
{
  ConnInfo *conn = (ConnInfo *)p;

  (void)ult;
  (void)uln;

  fprintf(MSG_OUT, "\nProgress: %s (%g/%g)", conn->url, dlnow, dltotal);
  fprintf(MSG_OUT, "\nProgress: %s (%g)", conn->url, ult);

  return 0;
}

/* CURLOPT_OPENSOCKETFUNCTION */
static curl_socket_t opensocket(void *clientp, curlsocktype purpose,
                                struct curl_sockaddr *address)
{
  fprintf(MSG_OUT, "\nopensocket :");

  curl_socket_t sockfd = CURL_SOCKET_BAD;

  /* restrict to IPv4 */
  if(purpose == CURLSOCKTYPE_IPCXN && address->family == AF_INET)
  {
    /* create a tcp socket object */
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket *tcp_socket = new boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket(io_service);

    /* open it and get the native handle*/
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    tcp_socket->open(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), ec);

    if(ec)
    {
      /* An error occurred */
      std::cout << std::endl << "Couldn't open socket [" << ec << "][" << ec.message() << "]";
      fprintf(MSG_OUT, "\nERROR: Returning CURL_SOCKET_BAD to signal error");
    }
    else
    {
      sockfd = tcp_socket->native_handle();
      fprintf(MSG_OUT, "\nOpened socket %d", sockfd);

      /* save it for monitoring */
      socket_map.insert(std::pair<curl_socket_t, boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket *>(sockfd, tcp_socket));
    }
  }

  return sockfd;
}

/* CURLOPT_CLOSESOCKETFUNCTION */
static int close_socket(void *clientp, curl_socket_t item)
{
  fprintf(MSG_OUT, "\nclose_socket : %d", item);

  std::map<curl_socket_t, boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket *>::iterator it = socket_map.find(item);

  if(it != socket_map.end())
  {
    delete it->second;
    socket_map.erase(it);
  }

  return 0;
}

/* Create a new easy handle, and add it to the global curl_multi */
static void new_conn(char *url, GlobalInfo *g)
{
  ConnInfo *conn;
  CURLMcode rc;

  conn = (ConnInfo *) calloc(1, sizeof(ConnInfo));

  conn->easy = curl_easy_init();
  if(!conn->easy)
  {
    fprintf(MSG_OUT, "\ncurl_easy_init() failed, exiting!");

    exit(2);
  }

  conn->global = g;
  conn->url = strdup(url);
  curl_easy_setopt(conn->easy, CURLOPT_URL, conn->url);
  curl_easy_setopt(conn->easy, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_cb);
  curl_easy_setopt(conn->easy, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &conn);
  curl_easy_setopt(conn->easy, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
  curl_easy_setopt(conn->easy, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, conn->error);
  curl_easy_setopt(conn->easy, CURLOPT_PRIVATE, conn);
  curl_easy_setopt(conn->easy, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1L);
  curl_easy_setopt(conn->easy, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, prog_cb);
  curl_easy_setopt(conn->easy, CURLOPT_PROGRESSDATA, conn);
  curl_easy_setopt(conn->easy, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_TIME, 3L);
  curl_easy_setopt(conn->easy, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_LIMIT, 10L);
  curl_easy_setopt(conn->easy, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
  curl_easy_setopt(conn->easy, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);

  /* call this function to get a socket */
  curl_easy_setopt(conn->easy, CURLOPT_OPENSOCKETFUNCTION, opensocket);

  /* call this function to close a socket */
  curl_easy_setopt(conn->easy, CURLOPT_CLOSESOCKETFUNCTION, close_socket);

  fprintf(MSG_OUT,
          "\nAdding easy %p to multi %p (%s)", conn->easy, g->multi, url);
  rc = curl_multi_add_handle(g->multi, conn->easy);
  mcode_or_die("new_conn: curl_multi_add_handle", rc);

  /* note that the add_handle() will set a time-out to trigger very soon so
     that the necessary socket_action() call will be called by this app */
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  GlobalInfo g;

  (void)argc;
  (void)argv;

  memset(&g, 0, sizeof(GlobalInfo));
  g.multi = curl_multi_init();

  curl_multi_setopt(g.multi, CURLMOPT_SOCKETFUNCTION, sock_cb);
  curl_multi_setopt(g.multi, CURLMOPT_SOCKETDATA, &g);
  curl_multi_setopt(g.multi, CURLMOPT_TIMERFUNCTION, multi_timer_cb);
  curl_multi_setopt(g.multi, CURLMOPT_TIMERDATA, &g);

  new_conn((char *)"https://www.google.com", &g);  /* add a URL */

  /* enter io_service run loop */
  io_service.run();

  curl_multi_cleanup(g.multi);

  fprintf(MSG_OUT, "\ndone.\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That particular example used to be broken and was [recently fixed](https://github.com/curl/curl/commit/ed2fcd54283179). Maybe you need that?

Comment: @DanielStenberg Let me first thank you for 1) making this helpful example, 2) replying to my issue personally. I've updated my post and my program with the code to what I've found in this URL https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/ed2fcd54283179dfb2fa52c6c4b08e1f4db9632d/docs/examples/asiohiper.cpp. It seems like there wasn't much difference from what was up there in the examples. The output is basically the same as you can see from the post edit diff.

Comment: I'm afraid my boost skills are virtually non-existent so I can't help much further, but there is more work on that example going on, like [here](https://github.com/curl/curl/pull/1219). It is apparently not in top shape yet.

Comment: @DanielStenberg I wonder if it is related to boost at all. It works when I don't use HTTPS. Is there a difference in the way libcurl calls the callbacks in HTTP and HTTPS that might warrant the crashing discrepancy? Also, the EXACT same code that you gave me and I'm compiling works no problem on Linux when compiled as "g++ -std=c++11 -lboost_system -lcurl -lssl -lcrypto -lz test.cpp -o test".

Comment: Hm then maybe you're seeing a bug. It *should* work the exact same way with HTTPS as HTTP as far as this goes.

Comment: @DanielStenberg You seem to be correct. I get further with the February 17, 2017 daily snapshot which seems to correct it. Thanks for your help!